# Specifying Super Class of a JAXB-Generated Class

Tags: java, jaxb

For JAXB-generated classes, is it possible to specify that they extend a particular class or can they only extend Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can with JAXB external binding.

You can read more here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/vendorCustomizations.html

Special tag you need is `<xjc:superClass>`